# Segfault moving (%eax), %ebx on the second iteration of this loop?

Tags: assembly, x86, att

I'm new in assembly and am trying to print one character of a string at a time, and currently have this so far.

```
    .equ  STDOUT,1
    .equ  WRITE,4
    .equ  EXIT,1

char_string:
    .asciz "hello, world"
    
.text
    .globl _start

_start:
    movl $char_string, %eax
    call print_str
    movl $EXIT, %eax
    int $0X80
    
print_str:
        mov (%eax), %ebx
        movl $WRITE, %eax
        movl $STDOUT, %ebx
        movl $char_string, %ecx
        movl $1, %edx
        int $0x80
        inc %eax
        cmpl $0, %ebx
        jne print_str
        je out_of_loop
out_of_loop:
    ret
```

However, when I try to compile I'm getting a segmentation fault at the line
`move (%eax), %ebx`
What's the problem with this? And how do I fix it? I'm trying to get the pointed char of the string to be moved to %ebx for the print and then later on I increment eax to move on to the next char in the string.

Comment: The `write` system call expects a pointer. So `mov (%eax), %ebx` is already wrong the first time around, it just does not crash. `eax` is used as the return value, so that's why it gets clobbered and causes the crash the second time around.

Comment: so should i be using [eax] instead of (%eax)?

Comment: Ah I see what you tried to do. `[eax]` is intel syntax, you can't use that and you overwrite `ebx` anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The direct cause of the crash is that `eax` is used as the return value of the system call. Your code is wrong in other ways too, however. I have commented your code:

```
print_str:
        mov (%eax), %ebx           # loads 4 bytes not 1
        movl $WRITE, %eax
        movl $STDOUT, %ebx         # overwrites ebx you loaded
        movl $char_string, %ecx    # uses the starting address instead of iterating
        movl $1, %edx
        int $0x80
        inc %eax                   # eax is return value of system call by now
        cmpl $0, %ebx              # ebx is $STDOUT, see above
        jne print_str
        je out_of_loop             # makes no sense to jump to next instruction
out_of_loop:
    ret
```

A possible solution could be:

```
print_str:
        mov %eax, %ecx             # address of char to print
        movl $STDOUT, %ebx
        movl $1, %edx
print_str_loop:
        cmpb $0, (%ecx)            # test for terminating zero byte
        je out_of_loop
        movl $WRITE, %eax          # reload eax as it is return value from a previous iteration
        int $0x80
        inc %ecx                   # point to next character
        jmp print_str_loop
out_of_loop:
        ret
```

Comment: is there a reason as to why you used cmpb in the first line of the loop? is cmpb comparing bytes?

Comment: Yes. The terminating zero is just 1 byte. All chars in a `.asciz` string are 1 byte each.